# How do I create predefined menus for my theme?

Tags: menus

This is my code thus far:

```
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
             'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
             'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

But this seems to only register 'locations' in which to place custom menus.
What I want is for all the custom menus (and menu items) to be fully setup on `after_theme_setup` or `init`.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you know the exact content etc for your menu there isn't much point in setting up the menu items. The custom menu locations are called in to the theme using wp_nav_menu();

Comment: I do know the exact content for the menus, and it needs to be used across many websites. So yeah ideally I'd like it to all be setup when the theme is activated.

Comment: @Vertaxe To detect theme activation you can do a boolean check like so: `isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example code taken from **new2wp.com** located [**HERE**](http://new2wp.com/snippet/register-and-create-new-nav-menus-with-default-menu-items/)

```
   // Function for registering wp_nav_menu() in 3 locations
    add_action( 'init', 'register_navmenus' );
    function register_navmenus() {
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'Top'       => __( 'Top Navigation' ),
            'Header'    => __( 'Header Navigation' ),
            'Footer'    => __( 'Footer Navigation' ),
            )
        );

        // Check if Top menu exists and make it if not
        if ( !is_nav_menu( 'Top' )) {
            $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( 'Top' );
            $menu = array( 'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 'menu-item-url' => get_home_url('/'),'menu-item-title' => 'Home' );
            wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $menu );
        }
        // Check if Header menu exists and make it if not
        if ( !is_nav_menu( 'Header' )) {
            $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( 'Header' );
            $menu = array( 'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 'menu-item-url' => get_home_url('/'), 'menu-item-title' => 'Home' );
            wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $menu );
        }
        // Check if Footer menu exists and make it if not
        if ( !is_nav_menu( 'Footer' )) {
            $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( 'Footer' );
            $menu = array( 'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 'menu-item-url' => get_home_url('/'), 'menu-item-title' => 'Home' );
            wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $menu );
        }

        // Get any menu locations that dont have a menu assigned to it and give it on
        /* Currently not working. couldnt fix it.
        $loc = array('Top', 'Header', 'Footer');
        if ( has_nav_menu( $location )) {
            $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
            return (!empty( $locations[ $location ] ));
        }
        */
    }
    /* Delete nav menu in case you need it
    wp_delete_nav_menu( $menu );
    */
```

Comment: The link is dead, thank you for including the full code in your post!

Answer (score 5):

For anyone seeking the same solution, here is the code:

```
function register_my_menus() {

    $menus = array(
        'Main menu' => array(
            'slug' => 'main-menu',
            'menu_items' => array(
                'Home' => site_url(),
                'Search' => site_url('/search/'),
                'Online now' => site_url('online-now'),
                'Video Chat' => site_url('/video-chat/'),
                'Galleries' => site_url('/galleries/'),
                'Forums' => site_url('/forums/'),
                'Live cams' => site_url('/live-cams/')
            )
        )
    );

    foreach($menus as $menu_title => $menu_var) {
        register_nav_menu( $menu_var['slug'], $menu_title );
        if( !is_nav_menu($menu_title) ) {
            $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( $menu_title );
            foreach( $menu_var['menu_items'] as $menu_item_name => $menu_item_url ) {
                $item = array ( 'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 'menu-item-url' => $menu_item_url, 'menu-item-title' => $menu_item_name );
                wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $item );
            }
        }
     }
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

All you need to do is modify the `$menus` array. :)

Comment: Excellent. I had to make a few changes to get it to work though